# Customizing linkifiication in Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, url

My employer uses a number of custom link shortcuts.  For example, b/ is the bug database.  This means that in IRC, we trade links like b/12345.

I'm running weechat in gnome terminal for IRC.

Is there a way to force the terminal (any terminal) to recognize b/12345 as a url?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a terminal emulator called "terminator" provides a plugin interface which allows setting up custom linkification.

The plugin docs I used are at https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins